# mysterious timeout error on VPS

Tags: php, timeout, fsockopen

So, the problem looks quite trivial - error "Connection timed out" in php function fsockopen().
BUT, I have feeling that I've tried almost everything on earth to solve this :(

Details:
Sever is dedicated on Hetzner, Debian 7, apache2, nginx, nothing special. When i try to use function with **IP instead of site name, it works**. Futhermore, **ping and telnet** works fine, php function  gethostbyname works too. I tried to check resolv.conf, it looks normal. I tried to flush Iptables settings, didnt help.
"allow_url_open" - on
"Registered PHP Streams" -  https, ftps, compress.zlib, compress.bzip2, php, file, glob, data, http, ftp, phar, zip
"Registered Stream Socket Transports" - tcp, udp, unix, udg, ssl, sslv3, tls.

I cant use cUrl or something else instead of fsockopen() because it's built-in module of site's CMS.

I check it with simple code

```
$fp = fsockopen("www.google.com", 80, $errno, $errstr, 10); // work fine 
if(! $fp) echo "www.google.com - $errstr ($errno)<br>\n"; 
else echo "www.google.com - ok<br>\n";
```

it doesn.t work. But if I use google's IP instead of domain:

```
$fp   =   fsockopen("93.158.134.11",   80,   $errno,   $errstr,   10);  // work fine
  if(!   $fp)
      echo   "93.158.134.11 -  $errstr   ($errno)<br>\n";
  else
      echo   "93.158.134.11 -  ok<br>\n";
```

It works.
On my another similarly configured VPS it says "ok" in both cases.

Comment: Usually that means that the connection to the server couldn't be established. Are you sure you're connecting to the right thing?

Comment: Yes, i'm sure. I'm using simple code for test: `$fp   =   fsockopen("www.google.com",   80,   $errno,   $errstr,   10);  // work fine
  if(!   $fp)
      echo   "www.google.com -  $errstr   ($errno)<br>\n";
  else
      echo   "www.google.com -  ok<br>\n";     `
It works on another server.

Comment: I added more info about testing in question body.